# Unity 5 Deleting Large Quantities of GameObjects (around 10000 or more) from Hierarchy

Tags: unity, c#

I've screwed up on this one. I used a script to randomly generate trees in my scene. The reason I did this instead of using the Mass Place Trees function in the terrain editor is because the trees all had a script attached to them, and Mass Place Trees does not keep the script attached.

It works, but instead of making my wanted 500 trees, I accidentally made  gigantic amount of 10000 trees. I've tried to delete them, but after selected every tree (or more than 50 or so, didn't really count, sorry) it freezes Unity so I can't delete them.

I really don't want to delete 50 trees at a time for the entire quantity of 10000 trees, it'll just take way too long. Is there a way to delete all of these trees at once so I can try my tree generation script again? Because the bright side is, the script did actually work.

Also, I can't play the game either, it takes minutes to actually boot up and it lags heavily. I really need to figure out how to fix this, but I'm not sure what to do, so I put my question on here for help.

Thank you.

P.S. If you ever, for some reason, want to take a look at my Mass Tree Generation script, here's the code:

```
public class MassPlaceObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tree;

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10001; i++)
        {
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, 10000), 500, Random.Range(0, 10000));
            Physics.Raycast(gameObject.transform.position, Vector3.down, out hit);
            Instantiate(tree, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it on my own by selecting everything in the current world scene except for most of the trees and copy/pasting them into a new world scene. I guess it was that simple >.<